# Nesting one template inside another with StringTemplate 4

Tags: template-engine, stringtemplate

I am having problem understanding how to nest another template inside another. For example, I have 3 templates: *application.stg*, *wrapper.stg* and *core.stg*.

#### core.stg:

```
page(data1, data2) ::= <<
  <h1>$data1$</h1>
  <h1>$data2$</h1>
>>
```

#### wrapper.stg:

```
page(data3, data4) ::= <<
  <h1>$data3$</h1>

  <!----- CORE.STG GOES HERE ------->

  <h1>$data4$</h1>
>>
```

#### application.stg:

```
   page(data7, data8) ::= <<
      <h1>$data7$</h1>

      <!----- WRAPPER.STG GOES HERE ------->

      <h1>$data8$</h1>
    >>
```

The documentation seems to hint that this is possible (Conditional Subtemplate section), but sorry, I could not figure out the syntax at all. Please help me out.

Comment: Could you provide a link to this *Conditional Subtemplate section*?

Comment: Sure, [http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST4/Templates](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST4/Templates), search for Heading "Conditionals".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a whole file with every template and make sure you set the `.stg` extension to it.
Then create a `TemplateGroupFile` object and set the properties `data7` and `data8` and tell it to start in the application template.

```
core(data1, data2) ::= <<
  <h1>$data1$</h1>
  <h1>$data2$</h1>
>>

wrapper(data3, data4) ::= <<
  <h1>$data3$</h1>
  core(data3,data4)
  <h1>$data4$</h1>
>>

application(data7, data8) ::= <<
  <h1>$data7$</h1>
  wrapper(data7,data8)
  <h1>$data8$</h1>
>>
```

This is the C# code

```
TemplateGroupFile grp = new TemplateGroupFile(Template);
Template page_tpl = grp.GetInstanceOf(GroupName);
GroupName = "application";
page_tpl.Add("data7", yourData);
page_tpl.Add("data8", moreOfYourData);
File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(dir, Path.GetFileName(outputFile)), page_tpl.Render());
```